# flashing Ubuntu on an Ipad

Tags: ipad, ios

does anyone know if it is possible to flash ubuntu or any other linux distribution on an ipad?
I am pretty annoyed by IOS and thought it a nice feature to switch totally to the linux OS. If one has an idea, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not at all possible.

Comment: Apple iOS bootloader is locked, and even if it's jailbroken, Ubuntu doesn't work on Apple devices.  This isn't really on topic, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is impossible, because there is no Ubuntu ISO that is supported with Apple Mobile devices. If you really want to have a Ubuntu on-the-go device try Ubuntu Touch: [Learn more here.](https://www.ubuntu.com/mobile) Remember that Ubuntu Touch is not supported with all devices, so look at the compatability list first.
(ANDROID DEVICES ONLY)